# SQL Where clause vs subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, query-optimization, where-clause

I've been reading various posts re the position of wheres in a SQL Query.

But does anyone have any idea about how they operate when a sub query is used?  I'm using Oracle 11g r2.

The reason I'm asking is because the following has a lot of CPU being used and I want to understand how to reduce this.

For example, Original code:

```
SELECT GREATEST(ABS.DATE_START, :B1)  CURR_REC_SD,
       LEAST(ABS.DATE_END, :B2)       CURR_REC_ED,
       ABS.DATE_START                 ORIGINAL_DATE_START
  FROM PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES ABS
 WHERE ABS.ABSENCE_ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID = :B4
   AND ABS.PERSON_ID = :B3
   AND (
         (   ABS.DATE_START BETWEEN :B1 AND :B2
          OR ABS.DATE_END BETWEEN :B1 AND :B2
         )
         OR (
            :B1 BETWEEN ABS.DATE_START AND ABS.DATE_END
         )
       );
```

vs modified code:

```
SELECT GREATEST(ABS.DATE_START, :B1)  CURR_REC_SD,
       LEAST(ABS.DATE_END, :B2)       CURR_REC_ED,
       ABS.DATE_START                 ORIGINAL_DATE_START
  FROM PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES ABS
 WHERE (SELECT ABS.DATE_START,
               ABS.DATE_END,
               ABS.DATE_START  ORIGINAL_DATE_START
          FROM PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES
         WHERE ABS.ABSENCE_ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID = :B4
           AND ABS.PERSON_ID = :B3
        )
    AND (
          (   ABS.DATE_START BETWEEN :B1 AND :B2
           OR ABS.DATE_END BETWEEN :B1 AND :B2
          )
          OR (
              :B1 BETWEEN ABS.DATE_START AND ABS.DATE_END
          )
        );
```

Will the latter reduce my CPU usage over that of the previous version?

Comment: Will the second query execute and give the results you expect?

Comment: It should give the same results as the first.  If I made a mistake in transcribing then my bad, my thinking is in the first there will be one plan to execute, but in the second two, the inner smaller select and then the outer.

Comment: I suggest executing both queries and see what happens. Best of luck.

Comment: It won't run as you have shown, as you aren't comparing your subquery results to anything. It also doesn't seem to be correlated to the outer query, so if it did run it would query the whole table for each row in the outer query. You sais you transcribed it; why not copy and paste what you are actually running, and show what the result is?

Comment: For me, the first one is the correct way to get your result. The second seems wrong. I think you wanted to do the where in 2 steps, but you will just increase your reading time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you intend with your second query, invalid as it is. Anyway, I see no sense in using a subquery in your situation. You want to select from the table where attendence type, person and certain date conditions are met. So select from that table and put your criteria in the WHERE clause, just as you are doing with your first query. I don't even see, how a subquery could possibly help here, as the first query is already the straight-forward way to the problem.

Simple rule: Keep your queries as simple as posiible. That makes them readable, maintainable and easy to handle for the optimizer.

There should be an index at least on `PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES(PERSON_ID, ABSENCE_ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID)`. Much better even on `PER_ABSENCE_ATTENDANCES(PERSON_ID, ABSENCE_ATTENDANCE_TYPE_ID, DATE_START, DATE_END)`. With the latter, it is not only all *criteria* in the index, so as to access table records quickly, but even all *data* needed in the query, so the table itself doesn't have to be read at all.